# Java: how to define the size of buffer to read all data from FileChannel

Tags: java

I have a pipe and I need to read data from it. However, as I understand before reading I must create buffer of some size. The question is how to define the size of buffer to read `all` data from pipe?

This is my code:

```
RandomAccessFile aFile     = new RandomAccessFile(PIPE_FILE, "r");
FileChannel  inChannel = aFile.getChannel();
ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocate(4);//temp 4
while(true){
    System.out.println("Size:"+inChannel.size());//returns 0
    int bytesRead = inChannel.read(buf);
    byte [] bytes=buf.array();
    ...
    buf.clear();
}
```

Comment: choosing this size of buffer is a trade off between time to read and memory. if you take smaller size it will take more time as more no of loop is used and if larger size then more memory is used. I have seen `1024` as comman value to be chosen.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you can't user [`Files.readAllBytes`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllBytes(java.nio.file.Path)) instead?

Comment: @BackSlash To tell the truth I don't know. In many examples I saw in internet people recommend to use RandomAccessFile to read data from named pipes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unlike a file, a pipe does not have a fixed size: for all we know, the writer on the other end of the pipe can be pushing data created algorithmically to you, so the pipe stream could be infinite.

You need to create a buffer of some size, usually in a hundreds to thousand bytes, read from the pipe in a loop, and either process the data stream as you go, or save it in a dynamically allocated buffer in a loop.

Answer (score 1):

I am not allowed to send comments yet, so I will answer based on my understanding:

I will focus on the fact this is a RandomAccessFile.

As suggested in another answer, regardless of the size of your buffer, you can read it in a loop up to the end:

```
while(inChannel.read(buf) >= 0)
{
}
```

Other than that, to answer your initial question precisely, even though your file/pipe will most likely keep growing, at a given time it has a size, so you can use that for your buffer, but if in-between file is modified then this could lead to incomplete read or even errors (for example if pipe would be cleared or something like that):

```
ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocate(inChannel.size());
```

Comment: Note: you want to use `>= 0`, not `> 0`. -1 indicates the end of the stream; 0 just means that no bytes were read *this time*, but some might be there next time.

Comment: Nice distinction there, will edit my post, thanks. Small details are key :).